# Instruction Pipelining - Architecture Simulator and Pipeline Visualizer

Tags: compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

I am working on a compiler, and had written an optimization which actually made my code slower! On investigating it, I found that there the code generator had decided to use a Handle (a double reference in case of our compiler) when my optimization was off, and a pointer to the Handle when my optimization was on! This resulted in one more de-reference instruction in the second case whenever the array was accessed.

But this single instruction caused a surprising 32% slowdown in the running time of the code. I am suspecting that this has to do with instruction pipelining as this extra de-reference causes 3 dependent instructions which might explain the slowdown.

I need to demonstrate the same and am trying to get more info on pipelining and it would be great if someone could suggest some good materials on instruction pipelining, useful architecture simulators and pipeline visualizers.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to dereference a pointer, you must first load the pointer from memory, and only then can you load the value that the pointer points to.  If you have a pointer to a pointer to a value, then you need to do three loads that are consecutive.  This is called pointer chasing.  If those pointers aren't in the cache, the performance impact can be huge.  Pipelining doesn't help much.  The standard book on computer architecture is hennessy & patterson.  There are several architectural simulators out there.  http://gem5.org is pretty popular (full disclosure, I'm a committer), but they almost always have a steep learning curve.